# How to get documents count returned by Model.countDocuments() function and set it to some other field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

I would like to SET ($set) the total 'count' returned by the below mongoose function to some other field in the different mongodb collection while updating(update query) the collection.

// Get count from User collection

```
   User.countDocuments({age:{$gte:5}}, function (err, count) { 
       if (err){ 
            console.log(err) 
        }else{ 
            console.log("Count :", count) 
        } 
    });
```

//Set count to the field viewCount in the StatChartMonitor collection as below

```
var user_id = '5e218e6811a54db030ff8f7b'; 
StatChartMonitor.findByIdAndUpdate(user_id, { viewCount: count}, 
function(err, docs) { 
    if (err){ 
       console.log(err) 
    } 
    else{ 
        console.log("Updated User : ", docs); 
    } 
});
```

Is there any way in mongoose to get that count(integer) value and set it in the update query ?

Comment: Show the update query

Comment: var id = '5e218e6811a54db030ff8f7b'; 
StatChartMonitor.findByIdAndUpdate( id, { viewCount: count }, 
                            function (err, docs) { 
    if (err){ 
        console.log(err) 
    } 
    else{ 
        console.log("Updated User : ", docs); 
    } 
});

Comment: I don't get the problem, you want to know how to use countDocuments and then update ?

Comment: I want to get the count or total number of documents in the "User" collection which matches the condition age:{$gte:5}.Then using this count value, i have to update the field called 'viewCount' in the "StatChartMonitor" collection as StatChartMonitor.findByIdAndUpdate( id, { viewCount: count } )

Comment: Please edit the question with all the informations

Answer (score 0):

```
async function countAndUpdate() {
  const count = await User.countDocuments({age:{$gte:5}}

  await StatChartMonitor.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: { viewCount: count } })
}
```

You need to add the keywords **async** and **await** in order to wait a Promise to be executed and access countDocuments result.

After that, you can findByIdAndUpdate with **$set**

Comment: Thanks for reply. But sorry this function does not update the field viewcount.The "id" should be passed to  findByIdAndUpdate({ viewCount: count })

Comment: Answer edited with id and $set as updated in question

Comment: No luck sorry. I have created separate thread with full problem statement at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64051687/mongoose-node-cron-job-to-update-the-mongodb-document-field-at-regular-time-int.   Please help